# Limit for modular prime counting of primes $6n\pm1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This post loosely extends the question and answers given here:

[Distribution of primes of 4n+1 and 4n+3 forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222644/distribution-of-primes-of-4n1-and-4n3-forms)

I need the following, extremely weak, constraint
$$\pi(x, 6, 1) \geq 2 \pi(x, 6, 5)$$
to be proven '*false*' and valid for an $x \geq N$ low enough so in a proof that uses the above constraint I can (if required...) numerically verify results up to $N$ and then rely on the proved constraint for $x \geq N$. The underlying math is however way out of my league.

We know that $\pi(x, 6, 1)$ and $\pi(x, 6, 5)$ are almost equal, and the difference shows some variations. Littlewood proved the following for the difference of the number of two different prime forms:
$$\pi(x, 4, 3)-\pi(x, 4, 1)
=\Omega_{\pm}\left(\dfrac{x^{1/2}}{\log x}\log\log\log x\right)
$$
**Q1**: What is the $\Omega_{\pm}(y)$ notation? Something like 'behaves like $y$, apart from an unknown constant'? I only have a reference to a publication I do not have access to where it should be explained...

**Q2**: If you take prime forms $3n\pm1$ or $6n\pm1$, does the same Littlewood formula apply? I see no reason why things would be different then.

**Q3**: Does a constant $c$ exists such that
$$|\pi(x, 6, 1)-\pi(x, 6, 5)|
\leq c\left(\dfrac{x^{1/2}}{\log x}\log\log\log x\right)
$$
or is it impossible to determine such a $c$? If I fit a curve for $c=3$ then I get this for $x$ up to 10 million:

[image: prime count difference]

The red fitted curve looks OK for $x>1000$ and seems to diverge from the actual prime count difference, but it's no proof. No idea what might happen at much larger values.

**Q4**: And if $c$ can not be determined, would it then be possible if the $x^{1/2}$ is changed to something as $x^{1/2+\varepsilon}$ which goes towards the much weaker constraint I started with above?

And maybe there is a much simpler insight which proves my original constraint to be false?

Comment: On the long run, there are about as many primes of the form $6k+1$ as of the form $6k+5$ , although this is not indicated numerically. Chebycheff's bias is the phenomenon that the primes of the form $6k+5$ appear to be preferred. I do not know whether the lead in the "prime race" switches infinite many often as in the race between the primes of the form $4k+1$ and of the form $4k+3$.

Comment: @Peter. It's exactly that 'not indicated numerically' that I like to see solved for some form of the Littlewood equation, or even for a much weaker relation that fits my needs. It's highly interesting stuff, but too complex for me to really dive into.